# GZIP не действует на css и jss

Tags: apache, .htaccess, gzip, netcat

Добрый день.

GZIP не хочет сжимать js и css

Вот код .htaccess (область с настройкой на сжатие)

```
AddType application/x-javascript .js
AddType text/css .css

<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on         Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk    Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file      \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^text\.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime      ^image\.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>

    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Однако html сжимает без проблем.

Возможно важные детали:

Стоит на netcat

Comment: *GZIP не хочет сжимать js и css* - а из чего это следует?

Comment: @klopp если вопрос о том как я это узнал. То я проверял тут http://highloadtools.com/gzip и на других сервисах

Comment: Зачем так далеко и так сложно? Вы же не знаете как именно оттуда запрашивают ваши файлы. Может что под исключения попадает, или ещё что-то. Проверяйте локально `wget -S http://ваш.css`, при необходимости добавляя строки User-Agent. И смотрите логи mod_gzip.

Comment: @klopp даже с консоли нет заголовка сжатия для css. А в каком виде должно сохранять файл через wget ?

Comment: Логи? См. `DeflateFilterNote` и пр. Ну и дефолты проверить типа `mod_gzip_minimum_file_size`